# strconv.ParseInt fails if number starts with 0

Tags: go, type-conversion

I'm currently having issues parsing some numbers starting with 0 in Go.

```golang
fmt.Println(strconv.ParseInt("0491031", 0, 64))
```

> 0 strconv.ParseInt: parsing "0491031": invalid syntax

GoPlayground: https://go.dev/play/p/TAv7IEoyI8I

I think this is due to some base conversion error, but I don't have ideas about how to fix it.
I'm getting this error parsing a 5GB+ csv file with gocsv, if you need more details.

[This error was caused by the [GoCSV library](https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv) that doesn't allow to specify a base for the numbers you're going to parse.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from [`strconv.ParseInt()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#ParseInt)

> If the base argument is 0, the true base is implied by the string's prefix following the sign (if present): 2 for "0b", 8 for "0" or "0o", 16 for "0x", and 10 otherwise. Also, for argument base 0 only, underscore characters are permitted as defined by the Go syntax for integer literals.

You are passing `0` for `base`, so the base to parse in will be inferred from the string value, and since it starts with a `'0'` followed by a non `'0'`, your number is interpreted as an octal (8)  number, and the digit `9` is invalid there.

Note that this would work:

```
fmt.Println(strconv.ParseInt("0431031", 0, 64))
```

And output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/boR8YIRX19_C)):

```
143897 <nil>
```

(Octal `431031` equals `143897` decimal.)

If your input is in base 10, pass `10` for `base`:

```
fmt.Println(strconv.ParseInt("0491031", 10, 64))
```

Then output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/v7-gvq5Ork0)):

```
491031 <nil>
```

Comment: If you expect decimal data (eg base 10 data) best to set the base of your data explicitly @Luca.

Comment: I don't really know how I didn't thought about it before asking, thanks!

Comment: If you want an `int` (as opposed to `int64`) use `strconv.Atoi()`, which is a shorthand for base-10 `ParseInt`. https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#Atoi The name comes from C function `atoi()`, where `a` stands for array, because a string is ultimately an array of characters.

Comment: @Zyl `a` stands for ASCII (a string), `i` stands for integer.

Comment: @icza This better show up in a text book as an example for Cunningham's law.